# copy the first table from doc1 and paste the table to doc2 in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to copy the first table from doc1 and paste the table in doc2 bookmarked place.Both documents opened by browsing method.

find below my error code

```
Sub MTRUpdation()

Dim myStoryRange As Range
Dim Current_MTR As Document
Dim module_name As String
Dim livcycle_version As String
Dim XML As String
Dim length As Integer
Dim finalString As String
Dim MIL_History, Test_sce_summary As Table
Dim Test_sce As Range


' Open current MTR document by dialog box
Set old_doc = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With old_doc
.Title = "Choose old MTR document"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
Set MIL_History = Word.ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set Test_sce = Word.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range
Set Test_sce_summary = Word.ActiveDocument.Tables(4)
'Word.Selection.Copy
End If
'ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
'Word.ActiveDocument.Close (False)
End With


' Open current MTR document by dialog box
Set myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myfile
.Title = "Choose current MTR document"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

'To get the file path name
fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)

'Activate the browsed document ie current MTR document
 Set activation = Documents.Open(fileselected)
Documents(activation).Activate



ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Delete


       'moving cursor to MIL author and version history position
     With Selection.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute findtext:="MIL author & version history"
    End With
   ' Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="MIL_Author", Range:=Selection.Range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="MIL_Author"
    'With
    Dim table_1 As Range
 Set table_1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MIL_Author").Range
 table_1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
 table_1.FormattedText = Test_sce.FormattedText
 table_1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
 table_1.Text = vbCrLf

  ' = Test_sce_summary.Range
    End With




End Sub
```

In my code i opened doc1 and copied the first table.Then opened doc2 added bookmark to paste the copied table.then go to the book marked places paste the copied table.This is what i want.please anyone help to get the correct code

Comment: What is the error and on which line??

Answer (score 1):

I see there will be a problem with the `With old_doc` statement. The `Exit Sub` needs to be part of the `If  ....... Then` and then the `Set`rows need to be part of the `Else`.

Also the way the documents are handled is incorrect.

I have tested this with two dummy documents, the "OLD" with four tables and the "NEW" with the text "MIL author & version history"

See if it works.

```
Sub MTRUpdation()

    Dim myStoryRange As Range
    Dim Current_MTR As Document
    Dim module_name As String
    Dim livcycle_version As String
    Dim XML As String
    Dim new_doc As Document

    Dim length As Integer
    Dim finalString As String
    'You need to have As .... after each element to Dim it as that element
    Dim MIL_History As Table, Test_sce_summary As Table
    Dim Test_sce As Range
    Dim table_1 As Range

    'OLD MTR
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

        .Title = "Choose old MTR document"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

        old_doc_FileName = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With 'Ending old MTR Dialog with

    'Opening the OLD MTR Doc
    Set old_doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=old_doc_FileName)

    Set MIL_History = old_doc.Tables(1)
    Set Test_sce = old_doc.Tables(1).Range
    Set Test_sce_summary = old_doc.Tables(4)

    'New MTR
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

        .Title = "Choose current MTR document"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

        new_doc_FileName = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With ' Ending Open current MTR document by dialog box

    'Opening the NEW MTR Doc
    Set new_doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=new_doc_FileName)

    new_doc.Tables(1).Delete

    'Selecting the entire doc
    new_doc.Content.Select
    'moving cursor to MIL author and version history position
    With Selection.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute findtext:="MIL author & version history"
    End With

    ' Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="MIL_Author", Range:=Selection.Range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="MIL_Author"

    Set table_1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MIL_Author").Range

        With table_1
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .FormattedText = Test_sce.FormattedText
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Text = vbCrLf
        End With

End Sub
```

There are many other things which can be corrected but I am not sure what some of the line are doing for your application, so I have left them.